# Why cant I blit multiple images?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm really new. I just want to make some simple games to get started and learn. I get the error: "Invalid Syntax" and only "pygame" is highlighted near the bottom of my code "pygame.display.flip()" HELP!

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()


display_width = 800         #sets width/height
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)             #sets colors
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
bright_red = (255, 0, 0)
sky_blue = (200, 230, 255)
green = (0, 200, 0)
bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
block_color = (53, 115, 255)

jet_width = 100            #sets jet width
BowserImgWidth = 100

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))  #sets surface name/size
pygame.display.set_caption('Bowser Hunter')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

JetImg = pygame.image.load('FighterJet1.png')
BowserImg_1 = pygame.image.load('Bowser1.png')
BowserImg_2 = pygame.image.load('Bowser2.png')

gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):

            gameLoop=False

    gameDisplay.fill(black)

    gameDisplay.blit(JetImg,(380, 450))

    gameDiplsay.blit(BowserImg_1(100(100))

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of syntax errors.  It should look like this:

```
GameDisplay.blit (JetImg, (380, 450))
GameDisplay.blit (BowserImg_1, (100,100))
```

If you look at your code, you had an opening bracket between your parameters.

Also you spelled gameDisplay: gameDiplsay.

Comment: Now i'm even more confused. I can get the JetImg to appear using the syntax i had, but no matter what I do--I can't get the second image to appear.

Comment: Sorry my first answer was wrong. I edited it and fixed your code. It was just syntax issues